# Go POST request to Third-Party API

Tags: api, go, post, request, go-micro

I am stuck wanting to do a simple POST request from my go microservice to Rapyd API.
I searched for many solutions on the web but none worked...
If I try to make the request, I either got a 400 Bad Request or an error containing "Network unreachable"
I tried making the body payload with Go structs, with JSON from string but nothing seems to work, here is my code : (Sorry I had to insert the structs with snippet because it wasn't working with code sample)

```js
type CardRequest struct {
    Amount        float64 `json:"amount"`
    Currency      string  `json:"currency"`
    PaymentMethod PaymentMethod `json:"payment_method"`
    ErrorPaymentURL string `json:"error_payment_url"`
    Capture         bool   `json:"capture"`
}

type PaymentMethod struct {
    Type   string `json:"type"`
    Fields Fields `json:"fields"`
}

type Fields struct {
    Number          string `json:"number"`
    ExpirationMonth string `json:"expiration_month"`
    ExpirationYear  string `json:"expiration_year"`
    Cvv             string `json:"cvv"`
}
```

```
    hc := http.Client{}
    form, _ := json.Marshal(CardRequest{
       Amount: 53.5,
       Currency: "THB",
       PaymentMethod: PaymentMethod{
           Type: "th_visa_card",
           Fields: Fields{
               Number: "4111111111111111",
               ExpirationMonth: "10",
               ExpirationYear: "21",
               Cvv: "123",
           },
       },
      ErrorPaymentURL: "https://error_example.net",
      Capture: true})
    http_method := "post"
    url_path := "/v1/payments"
    salt := strconv.Itoa(10000000 + rand.Intn(99999999-10000000))
    timestamp := strconv.Itoa(int(time.Now().Unix()))
    access_key := "my_access_key"
    secret_key := "my_secret_key"
    sign_str := http_method + url_path + salt + timestamp + access_key + secret_key + string(form[:])
    fmt.Println(form)
    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(secret_key))
    h.Write([]byte(sign_str))
    buf := h.Sum(nil)
    signature := base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(buf)
    httpReq, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://sandboxapi.rapyd.net/v1/payments", bytes.NewBuffer(form))
    // req.PostForm = form
    httpReq.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    httpReq.Header.Set("access_key", access_key)
    httpReq.Header.Set("salt", salt)
    httpReq.Header.Set("signature", signature)
    httpReq.Header.Set("timestamp", timestamp)

    resp, err := hc.Do(httpReq)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("payment request failed... %v", err))
    }
    bytes, err := httputil.DumpRequest(httpReq, true)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
    data, err2 := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err2 != nil {
        fmt.Println(err2)
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("payment body lecture failed... %v", err2))
    }
    fmt.Println(string(data))
    resp.Body.Close()
    // if data.status != "SUCCESS" || data.data.status != "CLO" || data.data.amount != req.Order.Total {
    //  return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("payment failed... %v", data.status.message))
    // }
```

Thank you very much for reading me, I don't what to do...
Don't hesitate to ask me for more informations and sorry if my english is bad!

**EDIT**

With my code I get this error : `Post "https://sandboxapi.rapyd.net/v1/payments": dial tcp: lookup sandboxapi.rapyd.net on [::1]:53: dial udp [::1]:53: connect: cannot assign requested address`

And with curl doing `curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"amount":9.99,"currency":"USD","payment_method":{"type":"us_visa_card","fields":{"number":"4111111111111111","expiration_month":"10","expiration_year":"21","cvv":"123"}},"error_payment_url":"https://error_example.net","capture":true}' -v https://sandboxapi.rapyd.net/v1/payments` in verbose mode I receive :

```
*   Trying 23.21.18.233...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to sandboxapi.rapyd.net (23.21.18.233) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with sandboxapi.rapyd.net port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 191 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 191 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with sandboxapi.rapyd.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with sandboxapi.rapyd.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 4096
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4096 length 4096
* schannel: encrypted data length: 4030
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4030 length 4096
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with sandboxapi.rapyd.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 1024
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 5054 length 5054
* schannel: encrypted data length: 232
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 232 length 5054
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with sandboxapi.rapyd.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 115
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 347 length 5054
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 126 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with sandboxapi.rapyd.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 51
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 51 length 5054
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with sandboxapi.rapyd.net port 443 (step 3/3)
* schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
> POST /v1/payments HTTP/1.1
> Host: sandboxapi.rapyd.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 200
>
* upload completely sent off: 200 out of 200 bytes
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 226
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 226 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 197
* schannel: decrypted data added: 197
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 197 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 197 length 102400
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 197
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Wed, 14 Apr 2021 06:16:04 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 11
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: W/"b-glZE90e6qywA5CDbvDnksw"
<
Bad Request* Connection #0 to host sandboxapi.rapyd.net left intact
```

Comment: What is the actual error message you are receiving? Are you able to properly hit the endpoint with the same request via a curl command?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply @Christian! 
I just edited my post with more infos

Comment: For the curl request, you aren't setting all the required headers (salt etc). The go error could be because you have run out of ports, how many go routines is this request running on?

Comment: Yes it's right for curl (I don't know how to calculate the in cli) and for Go I just found out my server has been hacked and ipv6 was disabled. This was causing the issue I'm pretty sure because now that it is enabled I have a proper error message telling me the signature is not good! I will have a look at that but it's another issue
Thank very much for your time and sorry for the inconvenience!